# Page space on RDL file

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, rdl

I have a rdl file. On the file, there are some controls and dynamic fields, also static contents.

When I want to print as a pdf or word file, The view is not okey. There are one space page between all page. My total page is 4 but with space takes 8 pages. Also on word file I can see half of my page. There is something wrong with width. I don't know further information with Reporting Services.

Here is the sample design code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
<Body>
 <Image Name="Image1">
    <Textbox Name="textbox30">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>İmza : </Value>
                <Style>
                  <FontFamily>Arial Narrow</FontFamily>
                  <FontSize>12pt</FontSize>
                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                  <Color>#595959</Color>
                </Style>
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style />
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <Top>82.77842cm</Top>
        <Left>14.80716cm</Left>
        <Height>0.6cm</Height>
        <Width>3.17147cm</Width>
        <Style>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
      </Textbox>
        <Source>Embedded</Source>
        <Value>imza</Value>
        <Sizing>FitProportional</Sizing>
        <Top>83.44898cm</Top>
        <Left>0.75225cm</Left>
        <Height>1.5cm</Height>
        <Width>4.94628cm</Width>
        <ZIndex>24</ZIndex>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Image>
</Body>
 <Width>22.52757cm</Width>
 <Page>...</Page>
   <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
   <DataSources>...</DataSources>
   <DataSets>...</DataSets>
   <ReportParameters>...</ReportParameters>
   <EmbeddedImages>...</EmbeddedImages>
   <Language>en-US</Language>
  <ConsumeContainerWhitespace>false</ConsumeContainerWhitespace>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Cm</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>0d2bcc46-f6d9-4a4b-b187-6092253641af</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

I need your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to the report page size. Please go to report property, change the page height and width. Also pay attention to the Margins, it will affect report items location in your print lay out. See last tip in the link below:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3023/sql-server-reporting-services-tips-and-tricks-to-improve-the-end-user-experience/